# JavaScript: Write Function That Executes Pig Latin on Phrase; Looping Through Appears to Give Strange Output

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to write code that does pig latin.  The two main rules are as follows:

- Rule 1: If a word begins with a vowel sound, add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.
- Rule 2: If a word begins with a consonant sound, move the consonant to the end of the word. Then finish by adding an "ay" sound to the end of the word.

There are some edge case rules that I'm not going to spell out here but are included in my code.

```js
const pigify = (str) => {
  let sentSplit = str.split(' ')
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < sentSplit.length; i++) {
    let element = sentSplit[i]
    console.log(element)
    // counts 'qu' as a consonant even when it's preceded by a consonant
    if (!['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0]) && (element.slice(1, 3) === 'qu')) {
      newArray.push(`${element.slice(3)}${element.slice(0,3)}ay`)
    }

    // translates a word beginning with three consonants 
    // counts 'sch' as a single phoneme
    else if (!['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0]) &&
      !['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[1]) &&
      !['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[2]) ||
      (element.slice(0, 3) === 'sch')
    ) {
      newArray.push(`${element.slice(3)}${element.slice(0,3)}ay`)
    }

    // translates a word beginning with two consonants
    // counts 'qu' as a single phoneme
    else if (!['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0]) &&
      !['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[1]) ||
      (element.slice(0, 2) === 'qu')
    ) {
      newArray.push(`${str.slice(2)}${str.slice(0,2)}ay`)
    }

    // translates a word beginning with a consonant
    else if (!['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0])) {
      newArray.push(`${str.slice(1)}${str[0]}ay`)
    }

    // translates a word beginning with a vowel
    else if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0])) {
      newArray.push(`${element}ay`)
    }
  }
  return newArray.join('')
}


const pigLatinString = pigify('the quick brown fox');
console.log(pigLatinString);
```

I expect the output of variable pigLatinString to be:

```
ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay
```

but instead my code returns:

```
'e quick brown foxthaye quick brown foxthaye quick brown foxthayhe quick brown foxtay'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good homework assignment I see.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to what I am missing in my code

Comment: Also how do you intend to handle the edge cases where y and w are vowels?

Comment: in my case, ignoring y and w for now

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hint: Spot the difference between `newArray.push(\`${element.slice(3)}` and `newArray.push(\`${str.slice(1)}`.

Comment: Having one long function do many different things is why you have problems understanding what's missing in your code. Break up the code into different functions who are responsible for small tasks....

Comment: @ melpomene: you are right!  That was the issue :)  ... thank you

Comment: Note, my homework comment is/was not meant as a disparaging comment at all, we all do things like this to learn or thoroughly understand a new subject, and also very similar things such as this are used in testing where a test case may have parameters to test a condition where we KNOW the result and test for that known even if it is a negative/false value.  As with nearly every problem there are multiple possible solutions.

Comment: Several good comments here, one about how to refactor to better resolve the original question (out of scope of this specific question but good as a comment) and others on what the actual issue is/how to solve that. @PineNuts0  To further gain insight/learn a new question (with the resolution of the original question in place) on how to refactor this to be a better solution might be good but it may fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ with a link to here, if worded right it may also fit here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doesn't cover edge cases:

Consider breaking up different "tasks" into different "functions" for readability and debugging purposes.

```js
  const startsWithVowel = letter => {
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    if (vowels.includes(letter)) return true;
  };

  const turnPigLatin = str => {
    const firstLetter = str.charAt(0);
    if (startsWithVowel(firstLetter)) {
      return str + 'yay';
    } else {
      return str.substr(1) + str.charAt(0) + 'ay';
    }
  };

  const pigify = sentence => {
    const words = sentence.split(' ');
    return words.map(word => turnPigLatin(word)).join(' ');
  };

  console.log(pigify('The quick brown fox'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the example above.  It makes sense to break down tasks into different functions.  I am guessing if I were to add edge cases then each edge case would be a new function that gets accounted for in turnPigLatin function?

Comment: Also, I'm over 30 and doing this for practice, not hw

Comment: oh my apologies @PineNuts0, it IS a typical homework assignment though. Sure, you could break it up such that EACH edge case is a new function as well. In general it is good practice to have small functions, that accomplish a small task. That way if something fails, you know what the culprit is. Check out functional programming for more info!

Comment: It doesn't directly address OP's question.